# For loops and floor division in python

Tags: python

I just had a question about this for loop

```
total = 0

for x in range(1,15,3):

    total += x

    total //= 2

print(total)
```

So the answer is 10 when I run it, but when I try to do it by hand I get 17. For example when I add up all the x's it will be 35. Then I floor divide by 2 which will give me 35//2 =17. I honestly don't know why its 10.

Comment: You don’t floor divide at the end only, you divide after each increment.

Comment: Indent *total //= 2* and you'll see the difference

Comment: Consider how many divisions are done in the loop versus how you got to 17.  You could try adding prints to see how total changes for each x

Comment: That's because total //=2 is inside the loop. Change indentation and it will work as you did manually

Comment: `sum(range(1,15,3))//2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is computing sums like this:

```
(((0 + x1) / 2 + x2) / 2 + x3) / 2 + ...
```

You can perform the division to see that this is *not* the same as `(0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + ...) / 2`. For example:

```
((x1/2 + x2)/2 + x3)/2 == x1/8 + x2/4 + x3/2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place total //= 2 outside the for loop. your code is finding the floor value of total in every iteration and overwriting total.

```
total = 0
for x in range(1, 15, 3):
    total += x
total //= 2
print(total)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Python the tab matters. The following will give you 17

```
total = 0

for x in range(1,15,3):

    total += x

total //= 2

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets floored in the loop, you're adding up the floored values.

You need to floor the sum, after the loop is done.

```
total = 0
for x in range(1, 15, 3):
    total += x
total //= 2
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0

for x in range(1,15,3):
    total += x

    a = total//2



print(a)
```